# Why is the concept in template template argument not verified?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, contravariance, template-templates

C++20 allows the program to specify concept for template template argument. For example,

```
#include <concepts>

template <typename T> concept Char = std::same_as<T, char>;
template <typename> struct S {};
template <template <Char U> typename T, typename U> T<U> foo() { return {}; }

int main() { foo<S, int>(); }
```

the first template argument of the function `foo` is expected to be a single argument template.

The concept `Char` is defined to be true only the type `char`, so an attempt to satisfy it for `int` shall fail. Still above program is accepted by all compilers: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/PaeETh6GP

Could you please explain, why the concept in template template argument can be specified, but it  will be still ignored?

Comment: Only guessing here, but probably for the same reason that a name for the inner parameter can be specified but it is ignored. You can apply the concepts to the "second" `U` in your example and it works as expected. Also note that a template with no valid instatiations is ill-formed NDR.

Comment: My guess is that `template <False U> typename T` requires that, whenever `False<U>` is satisfied, `T<U>` is valid, which is [vacuously true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).  In other words, `typename U` implies `False U`, whereas `False<U>` implies `True<U>` (with `True` being the concept counterpart of `typename`).  When `T` is used as in `T<U>`, the template that `T` refers to (namely `S`) is used directly, bypassing the `False` in the template template parameter.  (See [contravariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)))

Comment: Can be simplified to [that](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/cr77ejfP3) (removing `U`) IMO.

Comment: See [this](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.template#example-4) example in the draft standard.

Comment: @Fedor Your example is ill-formed, NDR because `False` is never satisfied. The duplicate question is not about substitution failure, but about why a program is ill-formed, NDR. This is a poor excuse to close the question, as the real issue has nothing to do with the NDR. Rewrite the question in such a way that the constraint is only sometimes satisfied, so that it is not ill-formed any more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A template (actual) *argument* matches a template (formal) *parameter* if the latter is *at least as specialised* as the former.

`template <Char> typename T` is *more* specialised than `template <typename> struct S`. Roughly speaking, `template <Char>` accepts a subset of what `template <typename>` accepts (the exact definition of what "at least as specialised" actually means is rather involved, but this is a zeroth approximation).

This means that the actual argument can be used in all contexts where the formal parameter can be used. That is, for any type `K` for which `T<K>` is valid, `S<K>` is also valid (because `S<K>` is valid for any `K`).

So it is OK to substitute `S` for `T`.

If you do it the other way around:

```
template<typename T> concept Any = true; 
template<typename T> concept Char = Any<T> && std::same_as<T, char>;

template<template<Any> class T> void foo();
          
template<Char> struct S { };
          
int main()  
{           
    foo<S>(); 
}
```

then this is ill-formed, because (roughly) you can say `T<int>` but not `S<int>`. So `S` is not a valid substitute for `T`.

Notes:

1. Why would we need this always-true concept `Any`? What's wrong with simply saying `template <template <typename> typename>`? Well, that's because of a special rule: if the parameter is not constrained at all, constraints of the argument are ignored, everything goes.
2. Why write `Any<T> && std::same_as<T, char>;`? To illustrate a point. The actual rules do not *evaluate* the boolean values of constraints, but compare constraints as formulae where atomic constraints serve as variables, see [here](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr.order#1). So the formal reason is that `S` has a conjunction of a strictly larger (inclusion-wise) set of atomic constraints than `T`. If `S` had the same or a strictly smaller set, it would be well-formed. If two sets are not ordered by inclusion, then neither template is more specialised, and there is no match.

Comment: "... then this is ill-formed" [It is not](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9TE461qcf).

Comment: Thanks. I made template-argument and template-parameter unrelated, and now GCC refuses the code: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/d7nT7vhM6. But Clang and MSVC still accept it, so I assume there are some bugs in them.

Comment: @Barry You are right, I forgot one rule: if the parameter is not constrained at all, constraints of the argument are ignored. I will fix the example soon.