# `requires` expression is evaluated to false in a nested template, but code is still compiled

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, requires-clause

I am failing to understand how the `requires` keyword works inside a nested template.

The code below can be compiled on the latest versions of MSVC and gcc (using `/std:c++latest` and `-std=c++2a`, respectively).

Is the `requires` simply discarded in scenarios like this? Should I not use it this way?

```
#include <type_traits>

template <
    template < typename >
    requires (false) // Should not this stop compilation?
    typename Wrapper >
using Test = Wrapper < int >;

template < typename >
struct S
{
};

int main() {
    Test < S > var;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried whether other compilers agree with msvc? (Godbolt compiler explorer is great)

Comment: Unrelated: if the code does not compile with `-std=c++20` your GCC install's not quite as latest as you think

Comment: `clang++` refuses it

Comment: @TedLyngmo But seemingly for the wrong reason. I don't think there is anything wrong with having the `requires`-clause where Clang complains about it. But compilation should fail because `Wrapper < int >` does not satisfy the constraints of `Wrapper` (at least intuitively).

Comment: @user17732522 I must admit I have very little xp when it comes to concepts in general and have a hard time wrapping my head around the requires thing in the question :)

Comment: @TedLyngmo It is just a template template parameter which has a requires-clause like any template could have in that position. Of course `requires(false)` specifically doesn't make much sense (and maybe is even IFNDR, don't know), but imagine it was `template < typename T > requires std::same_as<float, T> typename Wrapper` instead.

Comment: This would basically mean that this template template parameter should be passed a template template argument that would accept `float` as a template argument. But then intiuitively it seems that `Wrapper < int >` should fail, not because the actual template template argument doesn't accept `int`, but because the template template parameter asks only for a template template argument which accepts `float`, not `int`.

Comment: A bit of a side note, I believe the flag `-std=c++2a` is the temporary flag compilers use to allow you to opt-in to the WIP features for C++20 (similar to `-std=c++2b` for C++23), with complete features being activated with `-std=c++20` when available. Looking at cppreference's [C++20 compiler support page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20), it appears that Concepts are only complete in GCC 10, Clang 10, and only partially supported by MSVC 19.23-19.30. So it could be the case that whatever compiler version you're using doesn't fully support concepts yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the compilers are not implementing this correctly and you are correct that it should fail to compile.

In [[temp.names]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.names#7) it says that a *template-id* formed from a template template parameter with constraints must satisfy these constraints if all template arguments are non-dependent.

You are giving `Wrapper` only one argument, namely `int` which is not dependent. Therefore the compiler should check whether `Wrapper<int>` satisfies the constraint `requires(false)` of `Wrapper`. This check should fail.

I am not completely sure that `requires(false)` specifically is not IFNDR, because there are some similar rules forbidding e.g. templates which can never be instantiated, but the compilers seem to behave the same way if a non-trivial constraint is used.

Clang complains that the `requires` clause is a syntax error in that position, but I don't see any reason for that.

MSVC actually handles for example the following variation using a type constraint instead of a requires-clause as expected:

```
template<
    template<std::same_as<float> T>
    typename Wrapper>
using Test = Wrapper<int>;
```

but does not reject as expected if a requires-clause is used:

```
template<
    template<typename T>
    requires std::same_as<float, T>
    typename Wrapper>
using Test = Wrapper<int>;
```

Interestingly Clang crashes with an ICE on the former.

Comment: Somewhat similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68622369/why-is-the-concept-in-template-template-argument-not-verified

Comment: Clang issue reported: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/57410